# Wordpress / Modal / JS bug - modals stopped working suddenly

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, modal-dialog

I had site in pure JS and HTML and transferred it to WordPress. Everything worked fine until few days ago. Suddenly, my two functions on site stopped working, both are adding "active" class. First should provoke modal function and second is Tab function. It worked completely fine but suddenly not, I think that maybe it is because of wordpress update? This is page where is it not working:

https://lumitestx.lumitrix.eu/outdoor/ - second "slide", it is projector with Dots on it - it should provoke modal.

I have fully working version here: 
https://lumitrix-web.incolor.cz/outdoor/ 
This is how it should work. And it did, just suddenly stopped. Please someone know why is adding "active" class became a problem or what is problem? :) thanks a lot!

Here is Image of what part is broken

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing it working correctly on the second link (https://lumitrix-web.incolor.cz/outdoor/) as well. When comparing the two, I noticed that you have the "dots" setup with `data-toggle="#point-modal"` on both, meaning the modal container (div) would need to have a unique id of "point-modal".

On this site (https://lumitestx.lumitrix.eu/outdoor/) the modal container (div) is there but it doesn't have the point-modal ID attribute, so it can't find it.

An easy well to tell if it's missing is running `document.getElementById('point-modal') in the developer console.` It returns null on https://lumitestx.lumitrix.eu/outdoor/. So essentially you need to make sure the modal container that corresponds to each "dot" has the correct ID.

```
<div class="point skrollable skrollable-before" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#point-modal">
```

needs

```
<div class="modal fade" id="point-modal"....>
```

Let me know if you want me to elaborate on anything.

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. It is true that that way some type of modal will appear. But on site where it works it is not done by id="point-modal".  Maybe this will helps, the html + javascript for it.  [link]https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eXjbNr [/link]. It is script so that modals have paginations and u can click beetwen them. If u look at developer tool it will add active-point class but nothing appear and if u click on next dot it will add class again but not remove class from dot before. Problem is that code is exactly same on both sites. It worked for some reason it stopped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really clear on what you're asking exactly. The codepen is missing a number of dependencies, CSS & JS, so it's difficult to reproduce the functionality. I forked it (https://codepen.io/Jeff518Code/pen/ZPjdLL) and added some missing libs like jQuery and jQuery UI, but it's still missing too much to get an accurate representation. I'd have to see the code in its entirety. You're asking how to make sure the active class is toggled properly or how to make sure the pagination is working within the modal itself?